# Are there post-config variable change hooks in Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I'd like to automatically change certain config variables whenever another one is changed.

Right now, I have a script I run manually to do this:

```rb
foo = `heroku config:get FOO`.strip
/^(?<bar>[\w]+) (?<baz>[\w]+)$/ =~ foo
`heroku config:set BAR=#{bar} BAZ=#{baz}`
```

Is it possible to run this automatically only when `FOO` is changed? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Heroku Release Phase](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase) feature (currently in Beta).

With this, you can define a "release" script in your Procfile. The script will run in a one-off dyno after any event that triggers a new "release" for your app (e.g. a config var change). 
You could run your script in your "release" script. That way it will run whenever FOO is changed (although that is not the only trigger that will cause it to run).

Comment: Ahh perfect, I don't know how I missed that when Googling... one question though: I don't see anything in the docs regarding arguments -- would you know what arguments, if any, are passed to the release script?

Comment: You don't have to pass any arguments. You simply add a "release" process type in your Procfile, the syntax of which is just like any other Procfile entry.

Comment: Completely forgot to reply to this... I meant, what arguments are passed to the release script _by Heroku_? I guess I could do a fake release and see what pops up, but I was hoping there'd be more documentation on Heroku's site.

Comment: Heroku doesn't pass any arguments to the release script. You can pass it whatever arguments you want in your Procfile. Your release script can also access any environment variables you define (via heroku config:set).

Comment: Ah, so no easy way to know whether a release changed a config var then?

Comment: I think you might be able to get that information from within the release script by executing "heroku releases" there (or the corresponding Heroku Platform API call - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#release-list).
You would need to parse the output from "heroku releases" to see if the most recent release (i.e. the one currently in release-phase) contains a description such as "Set FOO config vars". I am not 100% sure about that, but worth a try.